# Attempt to apply Istio VirtualService to EKS cluster gets "no matches for kind "VirtualService"" but it is there

Tags: istio

I have two AWS EKS Kubernetes clusters; in both I am attempting to set up Istio to route traffic from outside the cluster to services within them.

The flow is Network Load Balancer -> Istio Gateway -> Istio VirtualService

Cluster A is working fine. Cluster B is getting an error trying to create the VirtualService. It is: `error: resource mapping not found for name: "service" namespace: "" from "my/def.yaml": no matches for kind VirtualService in version "networking.istio.io.v1alpha3" ensure CRDs are installed first`

If I do a `kubectl get crd` both clusters have the same number of entries including `virtualservices.networking.istio.io`. If I do `kubectl describe crd virtualservices.networking.istio.io` I get a long output for:

```
Spec:
  Conversion:
    Strategy:  None
  Group:       networking.istio.io
  Names:
    Categories:
      istio-io
      networking-istio-io
    Kind:       VirtualService
    List Kind:  VirtualServiceList
    Plural:     virtualservices
    Short Names:
      vs
    Singular:  virtualservice
  Scope:       Namespaced
```

Both clusters had Istio installed by applying 3 Helm charts from https://istio-release.storage.googleapis.com/charts, all v1.17.3:

- base
- istiod
- gateway

What could cause Cluster B to fail to apply a VirtualService with what sounds like a missing CRD but the CRD does appear to be there?

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the definition.

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io.v1alpha3`

should be

`apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3`